# How to add header file of 3d object into cocos3d?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, cocos2d-iphone, blender, cocos3d

I created the .h file from a 3d object that was made in Blender.  I want to use this object in  cocos3d but i'm not sure where i need to import the file and reference it to be visible in the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your exporting a .h file from Blender, you would need to write your own file reader to use this within in cocos3D.

Cocos3D already has native support for the PowerVR POD file format so the ideal solution is to instead export your 3D object as a Collada POD file. You can then run the Collada2POD convertor.

A Cocos3D guide for Blender to PowerVR POD is available on [Bill Hollings website](http://brenwill.com/2011/cocos3d-importing-converting-collada-to-pod/)